# Counting number of non-zero values

Tags: or-tools

Given a list of integers e.g., `[1,2,5,3,8,10]`, is it possible to create a constraint using a variable that represents the number of elements greater than 5? I have the following but it clearly doesn't count the number of elements:

```
bs = []
for i in range(6):
   b = model.NewBoolVar(f'b_{i}')
   p = model.NewIntVar(s, 50, f'p_{i}')
   model.Add(p >= 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
   model.Add(p < 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
   bs.append(b)

x = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'x')
y = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'y')
s1 = model.NewIntVar(0, 3, 's1')
#...
model.Add(s1 == sum(bs))
model.AddDivisionEquality(x, y, s1)
```

I can tell `s1` being 3, but the solutions are different to having `model.AddDivisionEquality(x, y, 3)`

UPDATE: It seems to give the expected result if `s1 = model.NewIntVar(1, 3, 's1')`. It's not clear why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the exact status of the solve().
It says model invalid as it reject models where the denominator can be zero.